# Android Studio design tab moved left

Tags: android, android-studio

Design screen moved left, and I can't move it back with horizontal scrolling bar. It feels like Design display have negative margin or something like this. How to fix it? Android Studio updated to the last version.

[image]

Comment: reinstall it? reset settings? Have you tried it?

Comment: change it to `Text` view, any difference obtained ?

Comment: Thanks, Vlad. Reset settings solved the issue. Please add the answer so I accept it

Comment: @VladMatvienko add this as an answer